# How did we know we can factor the following polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

Here is the equation I have $x^4 - 2 x^3 - 3x^2 + 4x + 2 = 0,$ the book said we can factor it to obtain $(x^2 - 2)(x^2 - 2x -1) = 0$ but I do not know how is this true, the rational root test does not say that $\sqrt{2}$ is a root. Can someone explain to me which theorem say this please?

Comment: Well, the quartic formula will tell you exaclty what the roots are. For reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation

Comment: That Rational Root Theorem can't tell you the square root of two is a solution since square root of two is irrational.

Comment: $\sqrt 2$ is irrational ...

Comment: Piita, TurlocTheRed, Digitallis: I believe that the OP knows that, whence his/her trouble about how to *guess* that factorization. @Emptymind: am I wrong? I.e. do you just want to be sure that this factorization is true?

Comment: To know that it's true, just multiply the factors to check. To guess those factors starting from the polynomial is a different harder question.

Comment: If you "know" that it can be factored, write it as $(x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)$ and see if that yields any solution.

Comment: In practice one would simply check in some CAS such as Maple/Mathematica whether it is reducible. Verifying is just expanding. Of course it depends on context (this would not make sense in exam/exercise setting).

Comment: @AnneBauval no that was not my problem ..... My problem was how to factorize it and why it is factorizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the rational root theorem fails, one potential route is to "conclude" *(perhaps falsely, but nonetheless proceed as if you have, since you might as well try **something**)* that you can only factor into two "nice" quadratics. Since the original polynomial is monic, we can go ahead and say, for some $a,b,c,d$,
$$
x^4 - 2 x^3 - 3x^2 + 4x + 2 = (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)
$$
Expand the right-hand side, and compare coefficients. You'll get a system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
a+c &= -2 \\
ac+b+d &= -3 \\
ad+bc &= 4 \\
bd &= 2
\end{cases}$$
From here, you should try to solve the system of equations. Of course, this is easier said than done, as you have no reason to suspect, *a priori*, that $a,b,c,d$ are "nice". However, again assuming they *are* nice (say, integers) should lead to the desired conclusion in this case.

For instance, if $a,b,c,d$ are integers, then $(b,d) \in \{(1,2),(2,1),(-1,-2),(-2,-1)\}$, and you can try to solve the system from there. Or you could use the fact that $a+c=-2$ to derive a substitution and perhaps clean the system up a bit. However you prefer to solve, you should arrive at the factorization with some trial and error.

---

Other routes than assuming the factorization into quadratics may exist, of course. Such as:

- You could try to see if this polynomial matches any familiar forms. This doesn't seem to, though, and this is a skill more honed by experience than anything. (In general, for instance, you might easily notice the binomial coefficients arising - not in this case though.)
- The quartic formula, but this is painful. You could try to find roots via any other method, too, that might seem plausible: numerical methods like Newton's method, for example. (They can at least provide guesses for roots that are easily checked.) From there, you could divide by $x-(\text{that root})$ and get a perhaps-simpler cubic, or iterate that method.
- More obscure tricks/tools of note may be [Ferrari's method for quartics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Ferrari_method), or [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs) and [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) for discerning the types or locations of roots, if you're interested.

Comment: Note that if you guess a value for one of a,b,c,d one can very quickly compute whether this leads to a solution for the other three variables. In particular guessing c=0 quickly leads to the correct factorization in this particular example.

Answer (score 3):

Any polynomial can be reduced to the depressed form with a linear substitution. In this case, the substitution $\,x = z + \dfrac{1}{2}\,$ results in a simple biquadratic, which is straightforward to factor:

$$
\begin{align}
x^4 - 2 x^3 - 3x^2 + 4x + 2 &= \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 - 2 \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^3 - 3\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + 4\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right) + 2
\\ &= z^4 - \frac{9}{2} z^2 + \frac{49}{16}
\\ &= \frac{1}{16} \left(4 z^2 - 9 - 4 \sqrt{2}\right) \left(4 z^2 - 9 + 4 \sqrt{2}\right)
\end{align}
$$

Recognizing that $\,9 \pm 4 \sqrt{2} = \left(2 \sqrt{2} \pm 1\right)^2\,$, each factor can be written as a difference of squares:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{16} \left(4 z^2 - 9 - 4 \sqrt{2}\right) \left(4 z^2 - 9 + 4 \sqrt{2}\right) &= \frac{1}{16}\left((2z)^2 - \left(2 \sqrt{2} + 1\right)^2\right)\left((2z)^2 - \left(2 \sqrt{2} - 1\right)^2\right)
\\ &= \frac{1}{16} \color{blue}{\left(2z-2\sqrt{2}-1\right)}\color{brown}{\left(2z+2\sqrt{2}+1\right)}
\\ &\qquad\;\;\; \color{brown}{\left(2z-2\sqrt{2}+1\right)}\color{blue}{\left(2z+2\sqrt{2}-1\right)}
\end{align}
$$

Substituting back $\,2z = 2x - 1\,$ and grouping the colored pairs produces the given factorization.

Comment: One should note that the substitution to create the depressed form eliminates the $x^3$ term and such a substitution always exists. In this particular example it so happens that this substitution also eliminates the $x$ term which makes the new polynomial easy to factorize.

Comment: @quarague Right, this won't work for factoring quartics in general. But reducing it to a depressed quartic is a natural first step, even if just attempting to solve it by traditional methods. In this case, it turned out to be a big shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's a trick specifically for seeking roots of integer-coefficient quartics of the form $\sqrt m$ where $m$ is a nonsquare rational number. Note that if $\sqrt m$ is a root of $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$, then it must separately be a root of both $ax^4+cx^2+e$ and $bx^3+dx$. (This is because
$$
a\sqrt m^4+b\sqrt m^3+c\sqrt m^2+d\sqrt m+e = (am^2+cm+e) + (bm+d)\sqrt m
$$
can equal $0$ only if both $am^2+cm+e=0$ and $bm+d=0$, since $\sqrt m$ is irrational.) In particular, the roots of $bx^3+dx$ (other than $x=0$) are $\pm\sqrt{-d/b}$, and so one can plug this into $ax^4+cx^2+e$ to see if it happens to be a root as well. For the polynomial in the OP, this works because $\pm\sqrt2$ are the nonzero roots of $-2x^3+4x$ and just happen to be roots of $x^4-3x^2+2$ as well.

To phrase this as a one-line test for such roots of integer-coefficient quartics:
$$
\text{If } bd\ne0 \text{ and } ad^2-cbd+eb^2=0 \text{, then } \pm\sqrt{-d/b} \text{ are roots of } ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e.
$$